# LWP realm in php curl

Tags: php, perl, curl, lwp-useragent

i'm having to write a script from perl to php.
a `LWP::UserAgent $credentials()` calls for the usual address, user & pass but also `realm`

What does realm relate to in curl? how can i set that opt?

---

**This question is not a duplicate.** if anyone had actually read my question, and the suggested duplicate you would see the answer on the other question informs of how to set `www-authenticate` from server using php.

I am attempting to connect, to a server which requires a `realm`.
Observe:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->credentials( 'X.X.X.X', 'Realm', 'Username' => 'password' );
```

So I ask, how does one replicate this function in PHP, using `cUrl`

---

Update:
The issue I was experiencing was due to .htaccess.
in regards to the `realm`, using a user & pass suffices for the connection